# Is there a C# .NET built-in conversion from a text of string(parameter i.e. filename and path) and fileinfo provided to an Image type?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

**PROBLEM:**

Do you know something in .NET that can convert my text(string) and return an image type? Like  .Net "Convert" Class does but it doesnt support image conversion.
I mean.. just like passing a file information (filename and Path) as parameters and return image(Bitmap) to display.
Do I really have to code this manually?

**SCENARIO:**

I **successfully** collect some list of image files in a directory(From Flash Drive or in local drive) and want to display those as an actual image.

Hope my problem is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending to whether you're using WinForms or WPF, you could use `System.Drawing.Image` or `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`.

You can't convert a string to an on-screen image. You HAVE to load it in another component. For example, `Image` has a static `FromFile(string filepath)` method that loads the image and makes it available for display.

Comment: FromFile() works.!!.Im just happy to know this method rather than doing it from scratch. Im still C# newbie. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the IValueConverter interface , and return the bitmap.

```
public class MyValueConverter : IValueConverter    {        

/*
Implement this method to modify the source data before sending it to display
*/
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)        {
            try            {
               return new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Images/" + (string)(value), UriKind.Relative));
            }
            catch{
                return new BitmapImage();
            }
        }
 /*
Implement this method to modify the target data before sending it back to the source.
*/

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)        { 
            var img = value as BitmapImage;
            return img.UriSource.AbsoluteUri;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Isn't this risky regarding memory consumption ?

Comment: i have not given this a thought regarding that, but my main goal was it was reusable across WPF,Silverlight,WP7...

Comment: True, but in my mind, using too many converters can slow a program considerably. I prefer to wrap my objects in types that expose something WPF can handle directly. I keep my converters simple such as `Boolean` to `System.Windows.Visibility` and back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Bitmap.FromFile("FileName")` or you can use `Image.FromFile("FileName")`.If you want to get an array of Bitmaps you can use a simple linq query

```
 var fileNames = new string[] { "file1", "file2", "file3" };
 var myImages = fileNames.Select(x => Bitmap.FromFile(x)).ToArray();
```